# '#' character Twitter post url in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, url, twitter

I am trying to publish a url with '#' char in twitter automaticaly like this:

```
https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?related=palcomp3&text=Confira!!&url=http://palcomp3.com/avioesdoforro/#!/de-costa-mainha
```

However Twitter ignores everything after the `#`

This is the code I tried:

```
[webView setUrlAddress:[NSString stringWithString:@"https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?related=palcomp3&text=Confira!!&url=http://palcomp3.com/avioesdoforro/#!/de-costa-mainha"]];
```

and

```
[webView setUrlAddress:[NSString stringWithString:@"https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?related=palcomp3&text=Confira!!&url=http://palcomp3.com/avioesdoforro/%23!/de-costa-mainha"]];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably due to the encoding, try using stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding to get a URL safe string, and use that as the URL

```
NSString *str=[NSString stringWithString:@""https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?related=palcomp3&text=Confira!!&url=http://palcomp3.com/avioesdoforro/#!/de-costa-mainha"];
str=[str  stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[webView setUrlAddress:str];
```